# Reference socket.io instance in another file with multiple exports (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am probably missing something, but I cannot get my head around on how to properly reference a socket (created with socket.io) in another file.
I have a server.js file:

```
const app = express();
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8081',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    allowedHeaders: ['my-custom-header'],
    credentials: true,
  },
});
require('./controllers/buildXLS.js')(io);
```

I want to access io in another file ('./controllers/buildXLS.js'):

```
module.exports = io => {
  io.on('connection', client => {
    client.on('subscribeToProgress', () => {
      console.log('client is subscribing to progress');
    });
  });
};
```

Now this works fine with `module.exports`, but a `exports.io = io =>...` crashes the server (require is not a function).
I do have several other exports in buildXLS.js, which will be destroyed by `module.exports`.
Is there any way around that? I need io in buildXLS.js, as it will emit progress updates.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below code I have exported io object from app.js and you can easily use it where you want

```
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8081',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    allowedHeaders: ['my-custom-header'],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
    console.log('socket connected', userId)

    if (io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms["room-" + userId] && io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms["room-" + userId].length > 0) userId++;
    socket.join("room-" + userId);
    io.sockets.in("room-" + userId).emit('connectToRoom', "You are in room no. " + userId);
});

const socketIoObject = io;
module.exports.ioObject = socketIoObject;
```

where you want to get that function use below code

```
const socket = require('../app');//import object

socket.ioObject.sockets.in("_room" + room_id).emit("hello", "how are you");
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I simplified it a bit (I am doing a fairly simple project without the need to differentiate namespaces and rooms).